# Trigger an alert in Azure when files stuck more than 30mins in BLOB folder

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

I am very new for the Azure have basic knowledge. Ideally we have job scheduled to pickup file from blob folder and move it another folder like archive based on number of mandatory files.

if the number of mandatory files not available in folder job will will treat incomplete and will not move to archive. so i need to notify user this and instead of going and check folders need to create an email alert.

was there any to set up an alert to trigger an email when files stuck in azure blob folder more than 30mins due to incomplete fileset ?

Answer (score 1):

> was there any to set up an alert to trigger an email when files stuck
>   in azure blob folder more than 30mins due to incomplete fileset ?

One possible solution would be to create a function that will be triggered based on a timer. You could trigger this function to run every 30 minutes. In that function you will list the blobs in the blob container which needs to be monitored. Based on the count of the blobs returned, you could send an email from that function itself.

More information about timer trigger for Azure Functions can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer.